# Заменить внутренние пробелы в строке на %20 используя цикл

Tags: javascript, строки, for, replace

Нашла решение, но оно достаточно запутанное и заменяет пробелы в начале и конце строки, а нужно их не заменять, а удалять. Решение должно быть только с использованием цикла без String.prototype.replace.  Помогите, пожалуйста с решением.

```
function replaceSpaces(str) {
    str = str.split('');

    let spaces = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === ' ') {
            spaces++;
        }
    }

    // i - указатель на текущий символ исходной строки
    // j - указатель на текущий символ новой строки

    for (let i = str.length - 1, j = str.length + 2 * spaces; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (str[i] === ' ') {
            str[j - 1] = '0';
            str[j - 2] = '2';
            str[j - 3] = '%';
            j -= 3;
        } else {
            str[j - 1] = str[i];
            j -= 1;
        }
    }
    return str.join('');
}

console.log(replaceSpaces("Lighthouse Labs"));
console.log(replaceSpaces(" Lighthouse Labs "));
console.log(replaceSpaces("blue is greener than purple for sure"));
```

Ожидаемый вывод должен быть таким:

```
Lighthouse%20Labs
Lighthouse%20Labs
blue%20is%20greener%20than%20purple%20for%20sure
```

Comment: а цикл обязателен? просто есть специальный метод ля этого

Comment: @StrangerintheQ к сожалению цикл обязателен. Такое условие.

Comment: А так не прокатит `encodeURI(" Lighthouse Labs ".trim())`?

Comment: @РустамГимранов оно то работает, но не соответствует условию) Нужно только через цикл

Comment: Еще вариант `Array.from(' Light Labs '.trim(), letter => ' ' == letter ? '%20' : letter).join('')`

Comment: @РустамГимранов здорово, но цикла нет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что это текст, который нужно преобразовать в ссылку. В JS есть дефолтная функция, которая делает это:

```js
var str = "   salam aleykum";
console.log(encodeURIComponent(str.trim())) //Output: salam % 20 aleykum
```

UPD:

```js
function replaceSpaces(text) {
  text = text.trim()

  var str = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == " ") {
      str += "%20";
      continue;
    } else str += text[i];
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(replaceSpaces("     red green blue"));
```

Comment: здорово, тоже работает, но согласно услови,  нужно это сделать через цикл)

Comment: Anna, обновил..

Comment: Замечательно, @teamspam !) Спасибо большое! Мне бы ваши мозги)

Answer (score 1):

Кажется так работает. Это надо?

```js
let str = 'blue is greener than purple for sure';
let str1 = ' Space before';
let str2 = 'Space after ';

function replaceSpaces(s) {
  let newStr = '';
    
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if(s[i] === ' ') {
      if(i === 0) continue;
      if(i === s.length - 1) continue;
      newStr += '%20';
      continue;
    }
    newStr += s[i];
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(replaceSpaces(str));
console.log(replaceSpaces(str1));
console.log(replaceSpaces(str2));
```

Comment: код работает, но если есть пробелы в начале и конце строки они тоже заменяются на %20, а нужно, что бы эти пробелы удалялись

Comment: @Anna Ага!! )) Вот, костыльно немного, но работает :) Хотя, через цикл только вот такими костылями. Методами строк или регулярками было бы очень лаконично и быстро.

Comment: да! Работает) Конечно методами строк или регулярными выражениями было бы быстрее и проще, но условие собюдено, поэтому все ок) Спасибо @AlexSazonov)

Comment: Если будет два пробела в начале или в конце - работать не будет(